# Javascript: Detect if device can make phonecall

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, browser

Is it possible to detect if a device can make a phonecall or not? I have a webpage with a list of phone numbers. I want to make them clickable if the device can call, using the `tel:` link. When I click on such a link in my desktop browser, Firefox reports:

> **The address wasn't understood**
>
> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (tel) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

I know about [mobile device detection](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/). This does not what I want, because most tablets are mobile but can't make a phone call.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to detect if a device can make a phone call using Javascript or HTML, and if so how?
- If this can't be done, what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Most devices that have browsers and can make calls will recognise a phone number in a page. So if it's clicked on (or some other suitable gesture), the device will highlight the whole number and offer to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS does this automatically, not sure about the other OS. But if you just check the devices by their name using simple Javascript/jQuery, wouldn't that be sufficient?

Something like this:

```
$.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: that would not detect the difference between a tablet (that cannot handle phonecalls) and a phone (a device that usually can detect calls)